# asp.net membership with MVC4

Tags: asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a project running on production with asp.net.
Now I need to create another project to administrate the site. So I decided to go with MVC4.
I have to use the same database, which has all the membership tables (aspnet_users and etc).

BUT MVC4 uses only 6 tables (Memberships,Profiles, and so on) with no 'aspnet_' in the left.

Now my problem is when I try to validate(Membership.Validate(username,password)) users in the existing database, the provider don't find the users. Because the provider is trying to search in the 'Memberships, users' table not in the 'aspnet_membership, aspnet_users' table.

In this case how would I integrate a new MVC4 project with my existing database ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC4 / .NET 4.5 Membership provider uses [SimpleMembership](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx) which has different table structures entirely.

However, it is apparently possible to change your provider back to the old .NET 2 provider in your [web config - see here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/9622).